# Unedited works of Sayana on Veda

Tags: vedas

According to the Wikipedia article on [Sayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayana) from the Vijayanagara Empire, he wrote a commentary on the Vedas. It also states that his commentary on Rigveda was edited and published by Max Müller.

I'm looking for the unabridged and unedited works of Sayana on Vedas.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want original Sanskrit work of Sayana or English translation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find original Sanskrit Sayanacharya Bhashya/works at [Internet Archive](https://archive.org) or at Digital Library of India.

Followings are some useful scanned books on Sayanacharya's Sanskrit 
Bhashya on Vedas:

- Rig Veda with Sayana's Commentary [Part 1](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart1), [Part 2](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart2), [Part 3](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart3), [Part 4](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart4)
- [A set of Yajurveda Sayanacharya Bhashya](https://archive.org/details/ASS042KrishnaYajurvediyaTaittiriyaSamhitaPart1KasinathSastriAgase1940) (9 parts)
- [Yajurveda Brahmana Sayana Bhashyam](https://archive.org/details/ASS037TaittiriyaBrahmanamWithSayanabhashyaPart1NarayanasastriGodbole1934) (3 parts)
- [Yajurveda Aranyaka Sayana Bhashyam](https://archive.org/details/ASS036TaittiriyaAranyakamWithSayanaBhashyaPart1BabasastriPhadke1898) (2 parts)
- [Atharva Veda Sayana Bhashyam](https://archive.org/details/atharva-veda-sAyaNa-bhAShyam) (9 parts)
- Sama Veda Samhita [Vol. 1](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.344920), [Vol. 2](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.514035), [Vol. 3](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.344954), [Vol. 4](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.487161) & [Vol. 5](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.487322)

Comment: I think OP wants English translations.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks for pointing out. I've just commented for clarification.

Comment: I wanted original Sanskrit works, thanks for the English translations too!

Comment: Very useful resource.

Comment: Can anyone please post the English translation links!