# Where I can find the English translation of Sayana's commentary on entire Vedas?

Tags: vedas, translation-request

I have seen a post where links to Sayana's commentary on Vedas in Sanskrit are there. But I want the English translation. Can somebody please post the links?

Comment: It's huge work I think the whole work may not be translated into English at all.

Comment: Related [Unedited works of Sayana on Veda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17418/3500)

Comment: An advantage is that you get to see Vedas in a near original form. If in English it may not transmit authentically everything, but we can read/understand faster.

Comment: I would suggest improving your knowledge of Sanskrit so that you can understand the original text. Having studied Sayana's commentary, I can say that there are so many words and phrases that I understood immediately in Sanskrit, but could not find equivalent English words. Translations will always be approximate because languages always carry the culture in which they are born. It's funny you say language is not relevant, and yet for thousands of years the Vedas were preserved in their original language despite new languages having come up.

Comment: Try here: https://archive.org/search.php?query=sayana